# How the vector of displacement? is represented of magnetic moment of pole model?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge

I've may been asking the really stupid question.

[image]

Cited from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment)

$$\boldsymbol{m}:=\text{magnetic moment}$$

$$p:=\text{absolute strength of each pole of a bar magnet}$$

$$\boldsymbol{l}:=\text{displacement vector?}$$

How the vector $\boldsymbol{l}$ is represented in which form?

I've may been of lack of knowledge of vector.

Of course I assume that the bar magnet is placed with some angle between the x-axis of Cartesian coordinate system and the bar itself.

Using $\exp(i\theta)~$ to represent $~\boldsymbol{l}~$? but it must be handled in Complex plane generally I think..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field of a magnet leaves from the north (seeking) pole and reenters at the south.  To be analogous to an electric dipole, the separation vector is defined as going from the south pole to the north pole (for any choice of real coordinates).  (Be aware that this model is only somewhat accurate for points whose distance from the poles is large relative to the pole diameter.)